# How do I stop Apple Software Updater from trying to install iTunes? (Windows)

Tags: itunes, updates

Whenever there's a Safari or a Quicktime update the Apple Software Updater pops up asking if want to update. This is fine, however it also auto-checks a box that says 'Install Quicktime + iTunes' that I have to uncheck. I know this is only a minor annoyance but it's happened so often that it really bugs me. Is there a way to say "I don't ever want iTunes" and therefore save me tens of man seconds a year?

This is for a Windows machine.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Select the update it is offering you (i.e., click on it), then in the **Tools** menu, select **Ignore Selected Updates**.

Comment: Amazing. I didn't even see the menu bar before. Blinded by rage/stupidity I guess. Thank you.

Comment: same here! great tip.

Comment: You're welcome. It's possibly the most annoying updater ever, isn't it. I reckon Apple to it on purpose to annoy Windows users. ;-) If I want to install iTunes I'll freakin' install it - so STOP BUGGING ME!

Answer (score 1):

That is why I never install Apple software update on windows anymore, as to a solution,

Open up Task scheduler in All programs, accessories system tools, then delete the  AppleSoftwareUpdate task an that should do it.

Comment: I don't think this does what they want.  Rather than just disabling the offer to install iTunes, your suggestion disables security updates for all Apple software on your machine.

Answer (score 1):

If QuickTime/iTunes/Safari are already installed on your machine, go to their options and deselect "Check for updates automatically"